# If-else in jQuery and incrementing a variable value

Tags: jquery, html, multi-select, if-statement

I want to put an if-else statement in jQuery and also increase a var named `count`.
How to do it?

I want to put many statements inside the if- and else-blocks:

```
var count= 1;
$('#MultiSelectItemID :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
    {{if count==1}} 
    {
        ......................
        ......................
    }   
    {{else}}
    {          
        .................
        .................
    }
    count++;
}
```

Is this the right syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure where the `{{` and `}}` came from (templates, perhaps?), but I think all you need is a plain-old Javascript if-else:

```
var count= 1;
$('#MultiSelectItemID :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
    if (count==1) {
        //...
    } else {          
        //...
    }
    count++;
}
```

Also, in case you didn't notice, at the end of this loop, the `count` variable will actually equal the number of elements plus one, not the actual count. You don't even need to get the count through incrementing a variable, as the `length` property of the jQuery object will equal the count.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index instead for making an extra variable:

```
$('#MultiSelectItemID :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
    if(i===0) {
        // is first
    } else {
        // not first...
    }
}
```